# django customize truncatechars

Tags: django, django-views

I'm using truncatechars but it have a problem; 
For example, content is:

> Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature

using `truncatechars:160` (`{% block description %}{{ content|truncatechars:160 }}{% endblock %}`) I get

> Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin litera

I want like this:

> Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin

Ie. if the word has reached the limit of 160 letters before the end of that word, don't include that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in `truncatechars` and `truncatewords` template filters do not support this directly, so [you will have to write a filter of your own](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters).

Luckily it's not very difficult – the basics are above and you can follow what [the built-in `truncatechars` filters](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa65b90a96f27dced8cfa89126d28186b4c80fbf/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L249) does and add a simple bit of logic to remove the last word too.

Comment: I used this to remove the "..." at the end, but I couldn't make this of it. @register.filter(name='truncchar')
def truncchar(value, arg):
    if len(value) < arg:
        return value
    else:
        return value[:arg]